# How many types of English are there?

Tags: american-english, british-english

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between the various dialects of English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36972/whats-the-difference-between-the-various-dialects-of-english)

I know of American English and British English, but how many other types of English are there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the various dialects of English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36972/whats-the-difference-between-the-various-dialects-of-english) - While not exactly the same question, the answers are for same.  Also see [question #22622](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22622/what-are-the-distances-among-the-major-english-dialects)

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? How many dialects are there of English? Because that's a very very difficult question to answer.

Comment: Wikipedia [has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dialects_of_the_English_language) of major ones.

Comment: The "duplicate" question doesn't mention Asian dialects of English. However, I believe the question is Not Constructive as it invites a list which can never be definitive.

Comment: I expect that the correct answer would be slightly in excess of two billion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the biggest but, there are more. Also, British English is misleading as a term. It's really more of a collective term for the different forms of the language, within the UK. Covering what is literally English (the language used in England) and the other, non-English British forms.

Comment: I'm reliably informed that Britain has far more dialectal variability than America, despite the fact that there are far less of us, and we live much closer together on average.